# Passing data from ListView row to an activity called via an onClick event

Tags: android

I have a ListView being populated via a SimpleCursorAdapter. The row uses a FrameLayout to allow the user to tap on the left or right side of the row, which will trigger two different activities. I have the tap working and they go to the appropriate activities, but I am stuck on figuring out how to make the resulting views show the data related to the row tapped on.

The code used to go to the new activities are:

```
public void goToCaptureBonus (View View) {
    Log.e(TAG,"goToCaptureBonus");
    Intent goToCaptureBonus = new Intent(this,captureBonus.class);
    startActivity(goToCaptureBonus);
}

public void goToBonusDetail (View View) {
    Log.e(TAG,"goToBonusDetail");
    Intent goToBonusDetail = new Intent(this,bonusDetail.class);
    startActivity(goToBonusDetail);
}
```

I am currently using the following in my `onCreate`, but I think this is trying to read the entire list view, not just the two frames I made in my row.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(bonusListing.this, bonusListing.class);
                startActivity(nextActivity);
            }
        });
```

I want to have the app pass the row data to the `goToCaptureBonus` and `goToBonusDetail` activities when their associated frames are tapped, so that those activities will know what data to read from my DB.

Comment: have you try .putExtra?

Comment: That does seem like it would work, but not sure how to pass it the tapped item. Each item in my ListView has a unique hMy column, so ideally I would pass the value of that. I was thinking `goToCaptureBonus.putExtra("hMy",int);`, but not sure how to pass the actual hMy value over (it is not displayed on screen). I could use a String, String version, but even though I have an sCode displayed on my row, I still don't see how to grab the value of the tapped one.

Comment: there should be a way to pass the Position

Comment: I can't give a full answer but View has 2 methods namely [setTag(Object)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()). You can use that to pass your data but you also need to create a subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter` so that you can override the default implementation.